# How do I open the VMware Remote Console (application) from the PowerCLI?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, powercli

A recent update to ESXi in our environment added a feature, "Open with VMRC".

[image: Piece of Web Client screen]

This works outside the browser, and as the method of accessing the console that functions inside the browser hasn't worked in my Chrome for months, this removal of a dependency is a welcome change.

Is there a way to open the console app from PowerCLI? I have v5.8.
I've looked into [Open-VMConsoleWindow](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FOpen-VMConsoleWindow.html), but it seems to be intended to open a browser window.

Is it possible to start this app in some way without mucking about in the vSphere web client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more than an hour of searching around and trial-and-error, i followed what Mario Lenz said:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Remote Console\vmrc.exe vmrc://[USERNAME]@[VC]/?moid=[VM-MOREF-ID]
```

[VM-MOREF-ID] can be found in the URL, in recent web client versions (i connected to the web client of an ESXI 6.5 vCenter). Open the web client, login and click on a VM. In the URL, at some point there is something like this:

```
:VirtualMachine:vm-324:
```

So, create a shortcut on your desktop with the following in Target:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Remote Console\vmrc.exe vmrc://[USERNAME]@[VC]/?moid="vm-324"
```

That should do the job. [USERNAME] and [VC] should be replaced with your username and vCenter Server address respectively.

This will ask you for the password of the username specified in the command line. You can omit the "[USERNAME]@" part from the command-line if you wish to be asked for the username every time.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have a look at VMRC yet and I'm no PowerCLI expert, but it looks like you can open a console like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Remote Console\vmrc.exe vmrc://[USERNAME]@[VC]/?moid=[VM-MOREF-ID]
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Remote Console\vmrc.exe vmrc://clone:[VC-TICKET]@[VC]/?moid=[VM-MOREF-ID]
```

[source](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2014/10/standalone-vmrc-vm-remote-console-re-introduced-in-vsphere-5-5-update-2b.html)

You should be able to get the Managed Object Reference ID of the VM (moid / VM-MOREF-ID) via PowerCLI somehow and then start vmrc.exe. Maybe you can even get your vCenter ticket and use the second way without needing to provide username and password.

Comment: +1. Omitting [USERNAME@] from the first example, vmrc seems to prompt for credentials. This is handy for emailing the the URLs to multiple recipients, for example.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: PowerCLI 6.5, announced on the [PowerCLI blog](http://blogs.vmware.com/PowerCLI/) 2016-11-17, installs VMRC and launches it with the Open-VMConsoleWindow command, ex.

```
Get-VM -Name *VM-name* | Open-VMConsoleWindow
```

---

Tunsworthy has posted the PowerCLI script [Open-VMConsole](https://github.com/Tunsworthy/PowerCLI/tree/master/Open-VMConsole) on GitHub to launch standalone VMRC.

Answer (score 1):

You can click on the VM in Vcenter. Right click and go down to console. Launch Remote Console. It will call vmrc.exe for you.